# media query-specified resolution different from reality

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I use:

```
@media(max-width:992px){
    h3{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

but in the browser it seems that the change does not happen at 992px, but when the screensize is at 887px or less. I have tried disabling css files one by one, but the problem doesn't seem to go away.
I can't figure out what the problem is.

EDIT: It must be something in the HTML file, because when I try the same code for another html file, it works properly. Also, I've noticed that boostrap's media queries are also not working properly (for example, if one of the breaking points is say 1200px, the changes happen at around 1120px in the browser). No idea what causes this. I've tried commenting different parts of the HTML, but it's always the same.

Comment: Is your browser window zoomed?

Comment: Try another browser.  If the issue is not present there, then it's probably the zoom as suggested by Turnip.  Try the shortcut CTRL+0 (or CMD+0 on mac).  It'll vary by browser client, but you can at least start there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given example it seems that you might be not closing } bracket also code should be like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {      
    h3{
      color:red;
    }    
}
```

You may check http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps link for more information Hope it helps!

Comment: sorry, that wasn't the problem, that was me copying the code wrong.

Comment: have you checked @media screen tag properly also in fire fox you may try if windows key shortcut Ctrl+shift+m to responsive frame and you may inspect your css. there might be possibility of some other style overwrites your desired style. if you provide jsfiddle link or your page link will be helpful to debug

Answer (score 0):

As Pravin vaichal, His guess must be true, You mised "}" bracket.

and you should write media query min-width to max-width too.

see [this one](http://rosanko.blogspot.com/2013/07/responsive-design.html) for more detail about media queries for responsive site.